# Why does JSON can't be used inside Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, json, function

I have this script:

```
<script>
function teste()
{
    alert("in");
    var ar_ida = <?php echo json_encode($arrayida); ?>;

    for(var i=0;i<30;i++){
         alert(ar_ida[i]);
    }
}
</script>
```

and it is called in this button:

```
<input type="button" value="teste" id="1" onclick="teste()" />
```

and for some reason it doesn't work. I've tried to remove de Json function and the script has opened. With the json function it doesn't even alerts "in".

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: What does the source of your script look like when opened in the browser, is it located in a php file?

Comment: what do you mean with that? json is a php function

Comment: Your JavaScript doesn't work … so show us your JavaScript. Not half the PHP used to generate the JavaScript.

Comment: What are your js errors?

Comment: yes it is in a php page.

Comment: @JRPR — JSON is not a PHP function, it is a data format that happens to conform to a subset of JavaScript syntax (which is what you are using it for).

Comment: Paste javascript code from your browser..

Comment: @360flow Michael, i did that and i found the notice and understood de error. My script block was before i declared the array, that was the problem. Thanks for the help, i wasn't aware that the script position in the page did matter.

Answer (score 1):

Because the PHP function `json_encode()` in your case is probably returning a javascript *object* of the form:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

instead of a javascript *array* of the form

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

as [mentioned in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), which cannot be iterated over with the `for` loop you are currently using.

Comment: json_encode can return an array as well

Comment: @RobotWoods But it obviously isn't because the javascript works perfectly fine if I put in an array manually...

Comment: Agreed, and I agree that how you've rephrased your answer now is likely the issue. I was not looking for nuance, how you had it before was blaming that function, not his input

Comment: The problem was the script position in the page, it was placed before the declaration of the php array. thanks for the help